# Symfony2, Sonata : translate and show translated roles name

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

The first step is more about Symfony2,

I have different Roles :

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_INVESTOR: [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_PROJECT_OWNER: [ROLE_USER]
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, SONATA]
```

I would like a french translation for each of them.

Either using roles.fr.yml, roles.fr.xml or roles.fr.xliff (not sure which one has to be used).

this is my actual yml :

```
'ROLE_PROJECT_OWNER': Porteur de projet
'ROLE_INVESTOR': Investisseur
'ROLE_USER': Utilisateur
```

or xliff :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xliff version="1.2" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <file source-language="en" datatype="plaintext" original="" >
        <body>
            <trans-unit id="ROLE_PROJECT_OWNER">
                <source>ROLE_PROJECT_OWNER</source>
                <target>Porteur de projet</target>
            </trans-unit>
        </body>
    </file>
</xliff>
```

(Both have not been tested)

Then i would like to show them in Sonata Admin, for now it is not user friendly at all :

[image: Roles]

This is how they are "auto" listed in this part :

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('username')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('enabled', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('locked', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('roles', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('createdAt')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

So it is not obvious how to add their related translations.

Any ideas how to do?

**UPDATE :**

I managed to have something more readable but not yet translated using custom template ([Sonata Doc](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html)).

```
{% block field %}
<div>
    {% for role in object.roles %}
    <strong>{{ role }}</strong> <br/>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also set the translation domain in your Admin class like :

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('username')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('enabled', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('locked', null, array('editable' => true))
        ->add('roles', null, array('editable' => true), array('translation_domain' => 'roles')))
        ->add('createdAt')
        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
                'delete' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

If it works, you might not even need to override the template.
Details in the Sonata Admin doc : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/translation.html#overriding-the-translation-domain

**UDPATE**

To translate filters you have to do something like:

**if your roles are from an entity**

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filterMapper)
{
    $filterMapper
        ->add('roles', null, array('translation_domain' => 'roles'), 'entity')
    ;
}
```

**if your roles are not from an entity**

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $filterMapper)
{
    // get all your availables roles
    $roles = array('ROLE_OWNER' => 'ROLE_OWNER');
    $filterMapper
        ->add('roles', 'doctrine_orm_choice', array('translation_domain' => 'roles'), 'choice', array('choices' => $roles))
    ;
}
```

I don't know if the translation will be available in the last case, you might need to translate in your controller the value of the roles.

Details from the documentation : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html

**UDPATE 2**

Here is a more detailed explaination for the second case, you have to create a method where you translate the value of your array. For example :

```
class ChallengeManager
{
    public function getStatuses($translate = false)
    {
        $statuses = array(
            ChallengeInterface::STATUS_DRAFT => 'challenge.status.draft',
            ChallengeInterface::STATUS_PUBLISHED => 'challenge.status.published',
            ChallengeInterface::STATUS_PENDING => 'challenge.status.pending',
            ChallengeInterface::STATUS_FINISHED => 'challenge.status.finished',
            ChallengeInterface::STATUS_PUBLISHING => 'challenge.status.publishing'
        );

        if ($translate == true) {
            $statusesTranslated = array();
            foreach ($statuses as $key => $status) {
                $statusesTranslated[$key] = $this->translator->transChoice($status, 0);
            }
            return $statusesTranslated;
        }
        return $statuses;
    }
}

class ChallengeAdmin
{
    protected configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
         $statuses = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer()->get('managers.challenge_manager')->getStatuses(true);
         $datagridMapper
             ->add('status',
                    'doctrine_orm_choice',
                    array(),
                    'choice',
                    array('choices' => $statuses))
    }
}
```

I use a service to handle the translations and retrieve the statuses, and I use it in my Sonata Admin.

Didn't find a better way at the moment to do the translations for choice fields.

Comment: That sounds perfect, i will still use the template since i need to add some styles. But i'd like to use it for the filters part. Do you know if it is working the same way? Basically i need the user to search the user with the translated role name and note with ROLE_XXXXX.

Comment: You have to use a choice type in this case, your translated value will be displayed for your user and the value field for each option will be ROLE_XXXX

Comment: Okay this is what i'm trying to do right now. It seems easy to do but i can't even add a choice type on the $filterMapper.

Comment: Thank you that is indeed working (except the translation on the second method, but that should be easy for that part), and i can get a select. But no result found using that method. I'm pretty sure it is the way to go. I'll keep digging it.

Comment: Great, i will search also if there is an easy way to do translations with doctrine_orm_choice. If you find out, i am interested !

Comment: Sure i'll update the post if i find anything related.

Comment: Nice, also i managed to make the search returning the right value, i replaced doctrine_orm_choice by null since ROLES are declared in my security.yml.

Comment: I have added more details on how to translate with the doctrine_orm_choice, it's not the prettiest way to do so, but that's the only way I found.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i finally managed to get the translation declared in my yml.

For reminder my translated roles are declared in Resources/translations/roles.fr.yml

```
'ROLE_PROJECT_OWNER': Porteur de projet
'ROLE_INVESTOR': Investisseur
'ROLE_USER': Utilisateur
```

I'm using custom template from sonata [doc](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/list_field_definition.html).

So i'm able to make a twig and straight translate here :

```
{% extends 'SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig' %}

{% trans_default_domain "roles" %}

{% block field %}
    <div>
        {% for role in object.roles %}
        <strong>{{ role|trans }} </strong>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```